# how to predict with pre-trained model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. I am trying to run a pre-trained NN for number recognition 'wide_resnet_28_10' from github- https://github.com/Curt-Park/handwritten_digit_recognition. When I try to predict an image it says expected input to have 4D. This is what I tried-

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy

model = load_model(r'C:\Users\sesha\Desktop\python\Deep learning NN\handwritten_digit_recognition-master\models\WideResNet28_10.h5')
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\sesha\Desktop\python\Deep learning NN\test_org01.png')
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
predictions = model.predict([img])
print(np.argmax(predictions))
```

most tutorial are vague, i did try np.reshape(1,X,X,-1) that didn't work.

Comment: You don't need `img = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)`.

Answer (score 3):

For the 4D input, it expects batches of data. You can make it a 4D tensor by doing:

```
predictions = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(img, 0))
```

if this does not work, try predict_on_batch instead of predict.

Also:
I don't think that your image reading is correct. It will probably give you a tensor of the byte string.

This should work

```
path = tf.constant(img_path)
image = tf.io.read_file(path)
image = tf.io.decode_image(image)
image = tf.image.resize(image, (X, Y)) # if necessary
```

Comment: the second code works and has (28,28,4) yet still i get "ValueError:Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 4)"

Comment: can you run model.summary()?
and also try printing the size of tf.expand_dims(img, 0).